# MySQL On Delete Cascade deleting everything

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a parent table (users) and a bunch of child tables which reference it with a FK. Right now, all my child tables have their FK's as on delete cascade, because obviously if a user gets deleted, I want all of its children killed. My problem is that for example if I have 5 records in my user table and I delete 1 of them, all records in my child tables are being deleted, including ones for the other 4 records. How can I make it so only children of the deleted user gets killed.

Parent Table

```
CREATE TABLE `user_gameworlds` 
( `PlayerId_FK` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GameId_FK` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Join_Date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `Login_Time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
 `Last_Update_Time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
  KEY `PlayedId_FK_idx` (`PlayerId_FK`),
  KEY `GameId_FK_idx` (`GameId_FK`),
  CONSTRAINT `GameId_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`GameId_FK`) REFERENCES `game_world` (`GameId`),
  CONSTRAINT `PlayedId_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`PlayerId_FK`) REFERENCES `users` (`PlayerId`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
```

[Parent table select statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzJok.png)

Child table

```
CREATE TABLE `province` (
`ProvinceId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`province_FK_PlayerId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`province_FK_GameId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Capital` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'Province',
`Population` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Morale` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ProvinceId`),
KEY `province_FK_PlayerId_idx` (`province_FK_PlayerId`),
KEY `province_FK_GameId_idx` (`province_FK_GameId`),
CONSTRAINT `province_FK_GameId` FOREIGN KEY (`province_FK_GameId`) REFERENCES `user_gameworlds` (`GameId_FK`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `province_FK_PlayerId` FOREIGN KEY (`province_FK_PlayerId`) REFERENCES `user_gameworlds` (`PlayerId_FK`) ON DELETE CASCADE
 )  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

[Child table select statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tmIu.png)

DELETE STATEMENT

```
Delete from user_gameworlds where PlayerId_FK = 9;
```

[Parent Table select after delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V5TP.png)

[Child table select after delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKj5R.png)

---

### EDIT: For anyone reading this, the answer to this problem is NOT using 2 individual FK's, but converting your table to using a composite primary key

Comment: Post the schema.

Comment: Show us the table definitions (incl pk's and fk's), sample data, delete statement, current result, wanted result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Sounds like something isn't set up right. provide an MCVE

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: The `province` table has `CONSTRAINT \`province_FK_GameId\` FOREIGN KEY (\`province_FK_GameId\`) REFERENCES \`user_gameworlds\` (\`GameId_FK\`) ON DELETE CASCADE`, which removes all `province` rows that have the game ID as the removed row of `user_gameworlds`. Am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

From [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table. Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported. Between two tables, do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.
>
> If a FOREIGN KEY clause is defined on both tables in a foreign key
>   relationship, making both tables a parent and child, an ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE or ON DELETE CASCADE subclause defined for one FOREIGN KEY
>   clause must be defined for the other in order for cascading operations
>   to succeed. If an ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON DELETE CASCADE subclause is
>   only defined for one FOREIGN KEY clause, cascading operations fail
>   with an error.

Your constraint

```
CONSTRAINT `province_FK_GameId` FOREIGN KEY (`province_FK_GameId`)
REFERENCES `user_gameworlds` (`GameId_FK`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

causes further deletions of players from user_gameworlds (from same game as the player you are removing) and those cause more deletions from province.

Comment: How do I avoid this? Because when I get rid of on delete cascade for game id my delete statements fail

Comment: Nevermind. I switched to using composite primary/foreign keys and my issue has been resolved